# Error converting data type varchar to numeric while inserting/ updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I was trying to insert/update records in bulk using merge statement. But I am getting following error. I have searched online i couldn't find a way to fix. Can some one tell me where I am doing wrong?

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric while inserting'

Table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE [Metric].[MetricGoal]
 (
    [metricGoalId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [profileConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [metricGoalName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [metricIndicatorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [marketConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [regionConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [goalYearConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [goalPeriodConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [targetValue] [decimal](20, 3) NULL,
    [actualValue] [decimal](20, 3) NULL,
    [metricGoalStatusConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ownerId] [int] NULL,
    [workerId] [int] NULL,
    [createdOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [createdBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [updatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lineOfBusinessConfigId] [int] NULL,
    [productConfigId] [int] NULL,
    [serviceAreaConfigId] [int] NULL,
  )
```

User Defined Table Type(created type with only columns that needs to insert / update):

```
CREATE TYPE [Metric].[MetricGoalType3] AS TABLE
(
    [metricGoalId] [int] NULL,
    [lineOfBusinessConfigId] [int] NULL,    
    [metricIndicatorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [goalYearConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [goalPeriodConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [marketConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [targetValue] [decimal](20, 3) NULL,
    [actualValue] [decimal](20, 3) NULL,
    [metricGoalStatusConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ownerId] [int] NULL,
    [workerId] [int] NULL
)
```

Stored procedure to insert/update using Merge:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Metric].[prMaintainMetricGoalBulkLoad]
    @currUserId INT = NULL,
    @currProfileConfigId INT = NULL,
    @tblMetricGoal [Metric].[MetricGoalType3] READONLY
AS
    DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE()
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO [Metric].[MetricGoal] T
    USING @tblMetricGoal S ON (T.metricGoalId = S.metricGoalId)

    WHEN MATCHED 
       THEN UPDATE
            SET T.targetValue = CASE WHEN S.targetValue = '' THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.targetValue,'')),T.targetValue) END, 
                T.actualValue = CASE WHEN S.actualValue = '' THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.actualValue,'')),T.actualValue) END,  
                T.metricGoalStatusConfigId = CASE WHEN S.metricGoalStatusConfigId =  -1 THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(S.metricGoalStatusConfigId,T.metricGoalStatusConfigId) END, 
                T.metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId = CASE WHEN S.metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId = -1 THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(S.metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId,T.metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId) END, 
                T.ownerId = CASE WHEN S.ownerId = -1 THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(S.ownerId,T.ownerId) END, 
                T.workerId = CASE WHEN S.workerId = -1 THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(S.workerId,T.workerId) END, 
                T.updatedOn = @now,
                T.updatedBy = @currUserId

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (profileConfigId,
                 --metricGoalName,
                 metricIndicatorId, lineOfBusinessConfigId, marketConfigId,
                 --productConfigId,
                 --serviceAreaConfigId,
                 --regionConfigId,
                 goalYearConfigId, goalPeriodConfigId, targetValue, actualValue,
                 metricGoalStatusConfigId, metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId,
                 ownerId, workerId, createdOn,  createdBy, 
                 updatedOn, updatedBy)
         VALUES (@currProfileConfigId,
                 --S.metricGoalName,
                 S.metricIndicatorId, S.lineOfBusinessConfigId, S.marketConfigId,
                 --NULLIF(S.productConfigId,-1),
                 --NULLIF(S.serviceAreaConfigId,-1),
                 --S.regionConfigId,
                 S.goalYearConfigId, S.goalPeriodConfigId,
                 CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.targetValue,'')),
                 CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.actualValue,'')),
                 S.metricGoalStatusConfigId, S.metricGoalStatusReasonConfigId,
                 NULLIF(S.ownerId, -1),
                 NULLIF(S.workerId, -1),
                 @now, @currUserId, @now, @currUserId);
END
```

Execution (used SQL Server Profiler to get below statements)

```
declare @p3 Metric.MetricGoalType3
insert into @p3 values(820,819,4,602,570,694,39.000,43.000,655,660,1585,NULL)
insert into @p3 values(NULL,819,4,602,570,1853,NULL,NULL,655,660,NULL,NULL)

exec Metric.prMaintainMetricGoalBulkLoad @currUserId=1618,@currProfileConfigId=301,@tblMetricGoal=@p3
```

Comment: use `try_convert` or `try_cast` instead of `convert` or `cast`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These 2 rows contain error:

```
T.targetValue = CASE WHEN S.targetValue = '' THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.targetValue,'')),T.targetValue) END, 
T.actualValue = CASE WHEN S.actualValue = '' THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.actualValue,'')),T.actualValue) END,
```

Both targetValue and actualValue are decimal(20,3), so how can you use `''` that is `string` with `decimal`s?

It should be

```
T.targetValue = CASE WHEN S.targetValue is null THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.targetValue,null)),T.targetValue) END, 
T.actualValue = CASE WHEN S.actualValue is null THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(S.actualValue,null)),T.actualValue) END,
```

even it has no sense but at least there vill be no conversion from `varchar` to `numeric`.

Here is how to reproduce your error (I'll use variables instead of tables):

```
declare @StargetValue DECIMAL(20,3) = 10, @TtargetValue DECIMAL(20,3) = 20;
set @ttargetValue = CASE WHEN @StargetValue = '' THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,3),NULLIF(@StargetValue,'')),@TtargetValue) END
```

When you try to confront your decimal with `''` you get the error because `''` just cannot be converted to `decimal`.

Comment: You are awesome. I did find where I am getting error but didn't find a way to fix it and it is now. Thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

There is data that will not convert correctly, exactly what or where I can't tell but since you indicate you are using SQL Server 2012 then use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) or [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) instead of `convert` or `cast`.

These 2 newer functions do not cause a failure if the data cannot be converted, they simply return NULL instead. While this may not solve bad data it does help. For example you can use these in a where clause e.g.

```
 select * 
 from to_be_imported
 where try_convert(date,stringcolumn) IS NULL
```

Comment: "I have tried"... *what?* Have you tried to isolate the problem(s) using try_cast in a where clause? I hope you realize all I can do is supply you with tools, I'm afraid you have to do the hard yards with the data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the insert portion of the statement does not align with your table definition. The third field in your insert list is lineOfBusinessConfigId which is trying to insert into the third field of the table, a varchar column metricGoalName.